# Как правильно получить размер файла с помощью std::experimental::filesystem? c++

Tags: c++, файловая-система

С плюсами только знакомлюсь. Пытаюсь получить список файлов и папок в директори и для файлов размер. Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string path = "C:\\";
    for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
        const fs::v1::path target(p);
        //bool x = fs::is_directory(target);
        if (!fs::is_directory(target))
        {
            try {
                std::cout << fs::file_size(target) << std::endl;
            }
            catch (fs::filesystem_error const & e)
            {
                std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Результат:

> ```
> C:\$GetCurrent
> C:\$Recycle.Bin
> C:\Config.Msi
> C:\hiberfil.sys
> Error: file_size(p): invalid argument: operation not permitted
> C:\HP
> C:\inetpub
> C:\Intel
> C:\My
> C:\pagefile.sys
> Error: file_size(p): invalid argument: operation not permitted
> C:\PerfLogs
> C:\Program Files
> C:\Program Files (x86)
> C:\ProgramData
> C:\Recovery
> C:\swapfile.sys
> Error: file_size(p): invalid argument: operation not permitted
> C:\SWsetup
> C:\System Volume Information
> C:\system.sav
> C:\test
> C:\Tool
> C:\Users
> C:\Windows
> C:\Windows.old
> C:\Windows10Upgrade
> ```

`fs::file_size(p)` дает такой же результат.
Как правильно получить размер файла?

Comment: на каком-нить нормальном каталоге попробуй...

Comment: @Fat-Zer хорошо, но как мне получить файлы из "ненормального" каталога?

Comment: список ты их получил, а на получение размера, очевидно, не хватает прав... возможно это действительно так, а возможно, проблемы в реализации (например для определения размера используется `open()`+`seek()` вместо `stat()`): слово `experimantal` намекает, что может не всё корректно работать... На сегодняшний день ИМХО надёжней использовать API ОС или сторонние библиотеки (хотя experemental по идее повторяет boost'овский).

Answer (score 1):

Размер доступен прямо в `directory_entry` (код для VS2017, стандарт c++17):

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    ::std::string path{"C:\\"};
    for(auto & p : ::std::filesystem::directory_iterator{path})
    {
        ::std::cout << p.path() << ::std::endl;
        if(not p.is_directory())
        {
            ::std::cout << p.file_size() << ::std::endl;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```